# regex: How to match similar strings with the same beginning

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match expressions with similar beginnings such as:

- "ThisExpressionContainsThis**Word**IntheMiddle"
- "ThisExpressionContainsThese**Words**InTheMiddle"

I can get both if the regex is `(Words|Word)`, but if the regex is `(Words|Words)`, it will only match `Word` instead of `Words` in both strings.

My use case will have those matching terms dynamically and they may come in disorder (I can't guarantee that `Words` will be before `Word`).

What's the most appropriate regex trick to match the exact words even if they start with the same characters?

--

To extend my use case, this is the example I'm working on:

```
  const terms = arrayWithTermsFetchedFromAnotherService.join('|');
  const termsMatcher = new RegExp(`(${terms})`);
```

Update:

I gave examples before with words surrounded by spaces "This expression contains this **Word** in the middle" and the regex `\b(Word|Words)\b` works, but if the word is part of the string (without spaces), that regex doesn't work. Mine doesn't include spaces.

Comment: ``new RegExp(`\\b(${terms})\\b`)``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I updated my example because that regex doesn't fit my use case. The terms I need to match are not surrounded by spaces but within another string

Comment: Ok, then just sort the terms in descending order. I updated the links on top, please see  if that works for you.

Comment: Simple. Thanks, @WiktorStribiżew!